# nodejs with general purpouse package manager

Tags: cross-platform, npm, composer-php, bower, package-managers

I'm trying to find the best way to use nodejs for a general-crossplatform package manager.
I've different projects from different repositories using various programming languages that , in few words , could be combined together to build a set of applications that can communicate with each other.

Now i would simplify the installation process avoiding use multiple manager for each language ( composer for php projects, bower , npm , git etc. )

Initially i thought to use only nodejs and npm to download all repository, but is there a way to specify custom packages with custom repository for various languages?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use npm as a crossplatform package manager. I think the best way for you to automate the installation (if that's what you want) is to create yourself an installation script which will use under the hood the npm, bower, ... scripts.

Comment: finally : https://github.com/hyperweb2/upt